# I keep getting the `objects' for nil class error while using the S3 library to upload image, why is this happening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm just trying to upload an image. The parameters I'm passing into the method are name, temp file (image), and the bucket. Via byebug, I can confirm all three exist when entering the method.

The first step is configuring the S3 manager object which I can confirm is not nil. I have also tried different series of keys/secret keys by recreating them off S3 so I don't think its a secret key issue.

I have discovered that when I call the service.buckets.find(bucket) method, it comes out to nil (hence the fatal error).

I don't know how to resolve this. I didn't create the back end, and trying to test it in my local machine (I'm sure its not an environmental variable thing, since this method connects directly to amazon, plus I'm hardcoding the secret keys in). The strange thing, is its working on production... I'm very confused and stuck, please any help would be welcome.

```
service = S3::Service.new(access_key_id: "***", secret_access_key: "***")
bucket  = service.buckets.find("bucket")

new_object = bucket.objects.build(name)
new_object.content = tmpfile
new_object.save
```

EDIT:

Apologies for an incomplete question. The error that shows is:

```
F, [2015-10-15T22:44:54.279053 #13942] FATAL -- : 
NoMethodError (undefined method `objects' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/uploader.rb:28:in `upload'
```

That hits exactly where I mentioned above, i.e. it cannot find the bucket, thus the bucket is nil, and the next line causes the fatal error.

Comment: Please post the error. Also, it wouldn't hurt to read the help section to see what all should be included in a proper question.

Comment: @WesFoster Sorry for the incomplete question. I posted the error, so hopefully you guys can understand the problem better. Thanks again.